# How to initialize Controllers fields when testing Spring Controller with MockMvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.4, using @AutoConfigureMockMvc to initialize MockMvc object. And testing the endpoints of my controller:

```
    mockMvc.perform(get(URL)).andExpect(status().isOk());
```

But I'm also have to mock a service in this controller. Tryed just to autowire this controller in the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyControllerIntegrationTest {
 @Autowired
 MyController myController;
```

And then tryed to set mock service for this object:

```
  FeignService feignService = mock(FeignService.class);
  //setting up some when() invocations
  //set feignService to myController with reflection
```

But when I perform mockMvc GET request and get into the Controller, there is another instance of MyController, not the one I set feignService to.

So how to set up the fields of tested Controller? How to set mocked service?

Comment: Use `@MockBean` and spring boot will handle it. Create a field of type `FeignService` in your test, annotate with `@MockBean` and run the test.

Comment: Thanks, it's working!